# How to tell if a given node is at root

Tags: c#, treeview, nodes

I have a test I'm going to be doing fairly often, so naturally I wanted to put it in a method.

In my treeview I have two buttons, left and right, which work to move a node up one tier (tier?  not sure on the correct word to use there) or down one tier.

However, some of the items in my treeview can only ever be placed as children of other specific items.  Some of the items can be placed as children OR as root nodes.

So I'm building a method where I pass in a child node and a parent node.  The child node is the node that will become the child of the parent node if the move is successful.  With a left click, that means the parent node is actually the parent of the child's current parent.  With a right click, that means the parent node is currently a sibling of the child node, and will become its parent.

I already know whether the node is root at the time I'm calling the function, so I could totally add a 3rd parameter to identify that... but why add additional complexity if there's already an easy way to figure this out that I don't know.  I figure that out using the whole tree view, but here I'm trying to do it with only the nodes.  Maybe that's bad, and I'm totally willing to accept that and change it.

I use my tags to store whole objects, but I gave my tree nodes their own images in imageindex, and I'm using that imageindex to determine what type of node I'm dealing with.  Thus, right now I have:

```
private bool TestNodeMovement(TreeNode child, TreeNode parent)
{
  bool returnValue = false;
  switch(child.ImageIndex)
  {
    case 0:
    case 1:
      if ((parent.ImageIndex == 2 && parent.ImageIndex == 4) {
        returnValue = true;
      }
      break;
    case 2:
    case 4:
      if ((parent.ImageIndex == 0 && parent.ImageIndex == 1) {
        returnValue = true;
      }
      break;
    default: //all other tree movement types are accepted
      returnValue = true;
      break;
  }
  return returnValue;
}
```

That very first one - 0 & 1 - those values can also be at root... so I need a test in there to see if parent is a root object.

I guess I could do

```
if (parent.Parent != null) { }
```

is there a better way?

Comment: Define a better way?  Alternatively, `if (parent.Level == 0)` would be a root node.

Comment: the parent has no parent, i.e. equals `null` <=> the parent is root.

Answer (score 0):

When you're inside a tree, the only real way to tell if you're at the root is to ensure no parent is specified. So, if you already keep track of parent to the node you're on, your if statement you referenced is the best way. For that method, you could even write a recursive traversing method to go up a tree until you find the root node if that's something you'd want to do as well. A simple null check is definitely the most performant way to do this.

If you don't have parent tracking already in your tree and you don't want to specify it (or can't if you're using an external Tree implementation), I would suggest your other method where you pass in the root and do a quick check in your method asking if the node is the same as the passed in root node.